# Keyup Event Listener not firing in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

```
var keysDown = {
};
//keyboard listener
window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
  console.log("keydown");
  keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;
}, false);
window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
  console.log("keyup");
  keysDown[e.keyCode] = false;
}, false);
```

Code above, this appears to work fine in Firefox and IE but for some reason Chrome(most recent version) is not picking up the keyup event. Any thoughts or advice would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It is working perfectly fine for me.

Comment: show the rest of the code.  clearly something else is blocking your event or  your code is never executed:  http://jsfiddle.net/ukxs6bLe/

Comment: same, works fine here (ubuntu+chrome)

Comment: See my site here: http://www.kadyszewski.com/home/home.php

it is not working for me in this instance.

Comment: or in this game I'm working on for fun I'm also receiving the same error: http://www.kadyszewski.com/brambles/zambles/index.html (WASD controls)

Comment: Do you mean keyup or keydown? Im seeing keyup but not keydown. EDIT: never mind, your console log is keyup for both. You might want to fix that :)

Comment: Ooops sorry on that site it says the keyup in the console becuase I put that in the log for keydown too there, Sorry! but I assure you the issue is with keyup. EDIT: I fixed it, sorry again!

Comment: You should probably use the document as the event listener src.

Comment: works for me in safari/chrome in mac.

Comment: Switched it over to document(good suggestion) as that is better practice anyways but it did not solve the issue :/ EDIT: scratch that I think that did fix my problem something else is broken :) Thanks! progress!

Comment: Thanks guys you helped me reach the bottom of this it is working as anticipated now. Y'all are awesome!